# How to find antilog(base 2) of a number?

Tags: c++, loops

I used a for loop to find antilog of the given number.

```
int g = 0, m, diff = 10;
for(j = 0; g <= diff; j++)
{
    g = pow(2, j);
}
m = j - 2;
cout << m;
```

It gives the power of 2 for which `g` is the number just less than `diff`.

I tried the base change theorem of log to find the antilog of the number something like this:

```
m = log(diff) / log(2);
```

without the for loop, but in this case whenever there is a number that is an exact multiple of 2s for example 8, then it gives 2 as the answer and not 3.

And using for loop for doing so is in a program is exceeding the time limit.

Is there a shorter and reliable way to do so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Note that dual tagging a question with C and C++ is apt to make people stroppy.  They're very different languages, and when you use `cout << m;`, you are clearly writing C++ code and should only use the C++ tag.  Occasionally, dual tagging is OK — but it would mean you are comparing and contrasting C with C++, or asking about the interworking of C and C++.  For general questions, choose one language; choose the language you're learning.

Comment: Exponentiation often gives results that are larger than an `int` can represent.

Comment: `pow(2, j)` should be better implemented as `1 << j`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fun solution without looping:

```
function antilog(int input) {
  int pow2 = input - 1;
  pow2 |= pow2 >> 16; // turn on all bits < MSB
  pow2 |= pow2 >> 8;
  pow2 |= pow2 >> 4;
  pow2 |= pow2 >> 2;
  pow2 |= pow2 >> 1;
  pow2++; // get least pow2 >= input
  return  // construct binary offset of pow2 bit
      ((pow2 & 0xffff0000) != 0) << 4
    | ((pow2 & 0xff00ff00) != 0) << 3
    | ((pow2 & 0xf0f0f0f0) != 0) << 2
    | ((pow2 & 0xcccccccc) != 0) << 1
    | ((pow2 & 0xaaaaaaaa) != 0);
}
```

The latter half of which was adapted from some part of the [bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html). (Knowing the source, there is probably some other function faster than this doing what you've asked.

Solutions aside, it should be noted that what particularly is causing your solution to be slow is the repeated calls to `pow`, which is a relatively expensive function. Because you are doing integer arithmetic (and what's more, multiplying by `2`, every computer's favorite number), it is much more efficient to write your loop as the following:

```
int g=1,m,diff=10;
for(j = 0; g <= diff && g <<= 1; j++) /* empty */;
m=j-2;
cout<<m;
```

Which is quite the hack. `int g=1` initializes g to the value it takes on the first time the code executes the body of the loop you've written. The loop conditions `g <= diff && g <<= 1` evaluates to `g <= diff`. (Notice that this is a problem if `diff >= 1 << (8 * sizeof(int) - 2)`, the greatest power of two we can store in an int). The empty statement simply allows us to have a well-formed for statement the compiler (mostly) won't complain about.

Answer (score 0):

Use integer arithmetic and build up the power incrementally.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int diff = 1; diff < 129; diff += 5)
    {
        int p = 1;
        int j;
        for (j = 0; p <= diff; j++)
        {
            p *= 2;
        }
        cout << diff << " = " << (j - 1) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
1 = 0
6 = 2
11 = 3
16 = 4
21 = 4
26 = 4
31 = 4
36 = 5
41 = 5
46 = 5
51 = 5
56 = 5
61 = 5
66 = 6
71 = 6
76 = 6
81 = 6
86 = 6
91 = 6
96 = 6
101 = 6
106 = 6
111 = 6
116 = 6
121 = 6
126 = 6
```

An alternative test strategy tests boundaries:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int diff[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 15, 16, 17, 31, 32, 33, 63, 64, 65 };
    int size = sizeof(diff) / sizeof(diff[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int p = 1;
        int j;
        for (j = 0; p <= diff[i]; j++)
        {
            p *= 2;
        }
        cout << diff[i] << " = " << (j - 1) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
1 = 0
2 = 1
3 = 1
4 = 2
5 = 2
7 = 2
8 = 3
9 = 3
15 = 3
16 = 4
17 = 4
31 = 4
32 = 5
33 = 5
63 = 5
64 = 6
65 = 6
```

Clearly, the inside of the test loop should be wrapped into an antilog<sub>2</sub> function — except for the printing operation.